# How to prove that $\operatorname{Card}(J) \leq \aleph_0=\operatorname{Card}(\mathbb{N})$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have this problem

Let the set $H=\left\{C_{(x, r)}=C((x, r),|r|)\right\}_{(x, r) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^*}$ where $C(\mathbf{M}, r)$ denotes the circle with center M and radius r. Let the subset $\left\{C_j\right\}_{j \in J \subset \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^*}$ be such that $(j, i) \in J^2, j \neq i \Rightarrow C_j \cap C_i=\varnothing$. Prove that $\operatorname{Card}(J) \leq \aleph_0=\operatorname{Card}(\mathbb{N})$.

..................

I suggest:

The set H contains the circles $C(x,r)$ such that the center belongs to $\mathbb{R}$ and the the radius belongs to $\mathbb{R}^*$ .

The subset $\left\{C_j\right\}_{j \in J \subset \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^*}$ of H, which is a set of circles that do not intersect with each other, i.e. $(j, i) \in J^2, j \neq i \Rightarrow C_j \cap C_i=\varnothing$

$\aleph_0$ is the set of infinite and well-ordered numbers.

$\mathbb{N}$ is the set of countable natural numbers.

Thus, we have to prove that the number of circles (that do not intersect each other) in the subset J must be ordered like the set $\aleph_0$ and countable like the set $\mathbb{N}$.

We can get the most posible number of circles ordered and countable (and do not intersect each other) when the centers of all of them are located in the center coordinates (0,0) and the radiuses of all of them  are graduated from lower value to the biggest value.

is my new answer correct, please?

[image]

Comment: Not enough for an answer, but: no, your answer is incorrect. You haven't used anything about the _specific_ set of circles presented, and the statement is false for circles in general (it's easy to get uncountably many non-intersecting circles on the plane; just take all the circles with a given center). You need to figure out what these specific circles have in common, and how you can use that to prove countability.

Comment: Anyway, "The number of any object is a positive number" is (at best) unclear, and "the set of natural numbers is also a set of positive, *infinite* numbers" is false.

Comment: The cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$ is $\aleph_0$, not "$\aleph$".

Comment: what I wrote is the all what I could do :( please help me

Comment: But you didn't do anything but toss around vaguely thought-out concepts that were not even correct. You need to review what it means for a set to be countable. You should also examine the geometry of the circles in $H$. What does it say about the circle that its radius is the absolute value of its $y$-coordinate? For the subset $C_J$ ($J$ itself is a set of points, not of circles), If $c_1, c_2$ are two circles in it, can $c_1$ be inside $c_2$?

Comment: I've edited my question and added a new  result check it please

Comment: "The subset $\left\{C_j\right\}_{j \in J \subset \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^*}$ of H, which is a set of circles that do not intersect with each other, i.e. $(j, i) \in J^2, j \neq i \Rightarrow C_j \cap C_i=\varnothing$". This is very unclear. And not even related to this sentence, what are we trying to find the cardinality of, ${C_j}$ or $J$?

Comment: I back the problem question because it's deleted by  mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

If I could guess from the text (which has many mistakes), you want to determine the cardinality of some set of disjunct circles in the plane? If that is the case, this could be a solution: Map every circle into some point $(q,w)$ from the that particular circle, where $q,\ w \in \mathbb{Q}$ (Function can be defined like this $f:Your\ set \rightarrow \mathbb{QxQ},\ f(A)=(q,w),\ where\ (q,w)\in A$. This is possible because $\mathbb{Q}$x$\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and since the circles are disjunct, the mapping is well defined. It is easy to show that mapping is "1-1" mapping, which implies that $Card(Your\ set) \leq Card(\mathbb{Q}$x$\mathbb{Q})$. It is common knowledge that $Card(\mathbb{QxQ})=Card(\mathbb{N})$. In case that circles can be put one into another like you wrote, this is not the solution.

Comment: after searching for solving this problem and asking many friends who are studying math, I've got that idea. all what I need is to prove that $Card(J)≤\aleph = Card(\mathbb(N))$. I started to doubt that the question has mistakes but the phD gave us as a homework.

Comment: This is definitely the answer IF the question is formulated as I mentioned.